# SQL Using Select MIN(Column) as input to where =

Tags: sql

I have a query which use `WHERE` clause to select particular value but instead of hard coding equal condition I want to use `SELECT` output of other query.

**Working Query**

```
from model
join upc 
on model.bucket_upc_id = upc.bucket_upc_id
join elect_prop 
on model.id = elect_prop.id
where upc.bucket_upc = 1234455 
 order by elect_prop.i_out as
```

I want to replace 1234455 with value from sub query

**Not Working**

```
from model
join upc 
on model.bucket_upc_id = upc.bucket_upc_id
join elect_prop 
on model.id = elect_prop.id
where upc.bucket_upc = BucketUPC
                       (
        select    bucket.bucket_upc as BucketUPC
                       from model as modelInfo
                           join upc as bucket on 
 bucket.bucket_upc_id=modelInfo.bucket_upc_id
                       where modelInfo.id = 179108
                       ) 
 order by elect_prop.i_out as
```

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result or just edit with current attempt query would helpful .

Comment: Edited with actual query

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Add a subquery in this way:

```
WHERE Current = (SELECT MIN(X) FROM MY_TABLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic example as to how to do it.  If you gave some table structure, we could potentially do better, but here ya go.

```
select
    *
from
    TABLE
where
    COLUMN = (select min(COLUMN) from TABLE);
```